# How to store datatable values into SQL table using SSIS. Is it possible to use Linq-to-SQL in SSIS using C#

Tags: c#, datatable, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

In SSIS, I need to store data table values into a SQL Server table using c#, but for my case, I don't want to use `SQLBULKCOPY` because I need to track the error which row causing an error while insertion. Is it possible to use Linq-to-SQL in SSIS?

Please provide the best method to insert. I am using Visual Studio Data Tools 2017. Target is SQL Server 2016.

Comment: The best method would be to use a Data Flow Task and configure the Error Output in the Destination Connection manager to A) not fail the component on error, and B) redirect the row to an error destination. Unless there's something else you're not telling us, you shouldn't need a script task to do what you want to do.